# CURL request with Retrofit2(kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, post, retrofit

I have a question.
I have never done curl requests, I don't know what to do, especially with Retrofit and it's interfaces.
I took a look at this
How to make a CURL request with retrofit?

example
curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: Basic auth-token" 
-H "Content-Type:application/json" 
-d "{"request": {"query": "HI"}}" 
"https://builder.pingpong.us/api/builder/1ca62a123185a612324ef24/integration/v0.2/custom/5d234ee2134aef2123"

Comment: Please do not post **sensitive information** such as Authorization header in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Curl is just command line tool for sending requests.
Retrofit is library for sending requests from phones.

You don't need to send curl from retrofit you just need to send request using retrofit.

for example:

> curl -X POST

in curl means that method is POST so you know your retrofit request needs to be POST.

Just go through retrofit documentation and examples and build request you need, also go trough curl documentation if you dont understand options (-H, -d)